# How to determine if a variable is immutable or not in an AST?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compiler-construction, immutability, visitor-pattern

I am working with the JavaScript AST as generated by [acornjs](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn). I have [normalized it](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/e5d06d98737154da86549ce0c3bdd1783251385f/index.js) such that every binary expression is assigned to a temporary variable to flatten it out, and variables are all defined one-per-line, stuff like that. Not entirely relevant for the question but just some context. I am writing a [transpiler](https://github.com/lancejpollard/js2link.js/blob/374182baf38870db19ad8d79034d19faf5127e98/index.js) from JS to a custom programming language. Now I would like to annotate the variables in the target language with whether the are mutable or not, sort of like in Rust.

How can/should I go about figuring this out programmatically? How do I identify every mutable and immutable variable and mark them appropriately? What is the general approach? It seems overwhelmingly complicated at first, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple/obvious.

I would think something along the lines of:

1. Look for `AssignmentExpression` nodes, where the `left` is an `Identifier`. Mark that identifier as immutable if it is only ever in the `left` position of an assignment once in the whole AST (after traversing to / visiting each node).
2. What about function parameters? I guess it doesn't really matter in JS because you can't reassign a variable on the outside when passed into a function like you can in C. But technically that does count as being *mutable*, since it started in the function param and was reassigned. But how to handle that or conceptualize of it?
3. Check `MemberExpression` nodes as well, see if the object property is reassigned.
4. That's about all that I can think of.

Do I have this about right? How can I do this properly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A JavaScript variable is immutable if and only if it is defined using the `const` keyword, but that doesn't seem to be your question. It looks like what you're actually asking is "How can I determine whether I can translate a non-const JavaScript variable to a const variable in my target language?", but that depends on a lot of factors. If const variables in your language work the same as const variables in JavaScript and you want to keep the structure of the original program as much as possible (i.e. not rewrite if-statements as ternaries or even rewrite loops as recursion etc.), ...

Comment: ... then you could ask "When can I replace `let` with `const` without breaking the program?" and the answer to that is "If there are no assignment statements with that variable as a target". Note that e.g. `const x; if (cond) { x = 42; } else { x = 23;}` is illegal in JavaScript - it would need to be `const x = cond ? 42 : 23;`. Of course I hav no idea whether the same is true in your target language.